# Query expressions over source type 'dynamic' or with a join sequence of type 'dynamic' are not allowed

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dynamic

I am passing an entity dynamically as a parameter. But, I am getting an exception while using linq with the same entity object.

Error:Query expressions over source type 'dynamic' or with a join sequence of type 'dynamic' are not allowed

```
private void CallCustomerCodeDynamically(dynamic customerEntities)
{
    var customerCode= from customer in customerEntities.CustomerInfoes
                   orderby customer.CustomerCode ascending
                   select customer.CustomerCode;
    ddlCustomerCode.DataSource = customerCode;
    ddlCustomerCode.DataBind();
}
```

Please give me a suggestion to resolve this.

Comment: Don't use dynamic.  Seriously, why are you using it?

Comment: `dynamic` has quite a few interesting uses. LINQ is not one of them.

Comment: I have two same DB instances, my code has to perform same logic with the users selected DB instance. I do not want to repeat the logic for the same purpose with different DBs. That is why.

Comment: That sounds like more of a case for a common base class than dynamic..

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, Linq does not play well with `dynamic`.  Linq makes heavy use of extension methods, which much be bound at compile-time and thus you can't use `dynamic` since it defers all binding to run-time.

If you have two datasets that do not have a common base type or interface, but have the same entity types (by name at least), then you'll need two overloads. You *might* be able to refactor part of it to improve reuse:

```
private void CallCustomerCodeDynamically(CustmoerEntities1 customerEntities)
{
    var customerCode= from customer in customerEntities.CustomerInfoes
                   orderby customer.CustomerCode ascending
                   select customer.CustomerCode;

    BindCodes(customerCode);
}


private void CallCustomerCodeDynamically(CustmoerEntities2 customerEntities)
{
    var customerCode= from customer in customerEntities.CustomerInfoes
                   orderby customer.CustomerCode ascending
                   select customer.CustomerCode;

    BindCodes(customerCode);
}

private void BindCodes(IEnumerable<string> customerCode)
{
    ddlCustomerCode.DataSource = customerCode;
    ddlCustomerCode.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: As was mentioned in comments, you're better off just using a common base type for the common members.

Comment: @Servy Sure, that would be cleaner - but I suspect these are unrelated datasets that just _happen_ to have the same types by name.